# Should I install meep using Ubuntu or Cygwin for windows?

Tags: python, meep

I'm new to using meep and don't know the difference between using Ubuntu and Cygwin.
The meep installation page recommends using Ubuntu, but it says this means that matplotlib plots won't show in the environment is this always the case? And if so is there a solution? Also is this only a problem if I used `import meep` will plots show up if meep isn't directly imported into the script?

Answer (score 0):

It has been working well for me using the ubuntu installation using MS using the WSL2
details here: https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-a-data-science-environment-using-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-c4b390803dd

Cygwin doesn't work as well.

For plots etc. installing jupyter (especially if using pymeep) and visualizing using jupyter notebooks running in a browser is recommended!